# How to prevent Jest from combining results?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I currently have two jest test cases the first one passes, but the second fails because its adding the sum of the previous case to that one

```
test('Subtotal to be 386.95 & VAT to be 54.173', () => {
    cart = ["tshirt", "shoes", "jacket", "blouse", "pants"]
    expect(calculateSubTotal(cart)).toBe(386.95);
    expect(calculateVAT(cart)).toBe(54.173)
})

test('Subtotal to be 30.99 & VAT to be 4.388', () => {
    cart = ["tshirt"]
    expect(calculateSubTotal(cart)).toBe(30.99);
    expect(calculateVAT(cart)).toBe(4.338)
});
```

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 30.99
    Received: 417.94
```

`calculateSubTotal` implementation:

`cart.js`

```
let products = {...} // products map by product name
let subTotal = 0 // line number 60

function calculateSubTotal(cart) {
    // line number 75
    for (i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
        switch (cart[i]) {
            case ("tshirt"):
                subTotal += products.tshirt.price
                break
            case ("blouse"):
                subTotal += products.blouse.price
                break
            // ... other product
        }
    }
    subTotal = Number(subTotal.toFixed(2))
    return subTotal
}

module.exports.calculateSubTotal = calculateSubTotal;

// another function
```

What do I need to do for jest to break out of the first test and not combine the test results?

Comment: Update your production code for `calculateSubTotal` function.

Comment: @hoangdv could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: I guess your test is working well, let's check `calculateSubTotal` logic again.

Comment: @hoangdv Here's a gist of my code: https://gist.github.com/dmc08/f3a52c41690d376d4fa5baf05a9d61ec

Comment: Move line number 60 to 75.